# Error in angular after upgrade from angular 7 to angular 8

Tags: angular

I upgraded angular from angular 7.3.9 to angular 8 and the ng serve command is throwing the following errors:
any help would be appreciated.
The errors are like so:

`ERROR in ./node_modules/prosemirror-commands/dist/index.mjs 362:53-65
Can't import the named export 'AllSelection' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)`

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing node_modules and reinstalling them?

Comment: what are your node and npm versions?

Comment: node version is 12.13.1 npm version is 6.12.1

Comment: @callback yes tried that several times

Comment: I have the same issue in Vue 2.6, tried every webpack configuration possible, till now nothing worked

Comment: Seems like ProseMirror guys are talking about it right now on this thread https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror/issues/1003

Comment: It appears they fixed it, so I tried removing the node_modules and run the build again and the build was successfull

Comment: @AndreiMaieras I removed node_modules myself several times, it is still not working

Comment: Have you tried it in the last couple of hours? the fix was pushed about that time? This is the command that I'm using `rm -fr node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install --force && yarn serve`

Comment: They basically reverted the `index.mjs` files to `index.js` in the dist folder because webpack does not know to handle this for some reason

Comment: @AndreiMaieras I am not using yarn for the projects and seems like I am still getting that mjs file

Comment: Hmm, can you update your question with the content of your `package.json` file?

Comment: @AndreiMaieras that got resolved, the issue was that i had kendo-editor as a dependency and that had a dependency on prosemirror, looks like either kendo or prosemirror fixed it, the issue has now been resolved I checked about an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by `"@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^0.10.3"` which was installed in my project.

The temporary solution was to remove it and reinstall, because this package was using the package `prosemirror-commands` which had issues, as `@progress/kendo-angular-editor` and it works now.
Below are the steps taken:

`npm uninstall @progress/kendo-angular-editor
npm install @progress/kendo-angular-editor`